# Support for Authorize.Net webhooks in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, authorize.net

Is there support for Authorize.Net webhooks in asp.net?

I am using Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.Receivers package. Is this correct ?Since other packages are specific to Github, and others ?

```
Public Sub Register(ByVal config As HttpConfiguration)

    ' Web API configuration and services

    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes()

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name:="WebHook_Authorizr",,
        routeTemplate:="api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults:=New With {.id = RouteParameter.Optional}
    )

    config.   <<<<<<  which method to be called here ????
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

No Need to use any webhook package. you should create one task which read the string and you can read the response from **request.body**  using stream reader.

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Request.Body, Encoding.UTF8)){var 
responseBody = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();}
```

after that deserialize response body.